# Using PrintWriter to print an array

Tags: java, arrays, printstream

I have an array named theDirectory, which holds many DirectoryEntrys, each consisting of a name and telno. I now need to print each DirectoryEntry inside theDirectory into a text file.
This is the method I have tried, however i am getting the error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.

My code:

```
public void save() {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("directory.txt", true)); 

    for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
        pw.write(x.getName());
        pw.write(x.getNumber());
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

any help on this matter would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand about checked exceptions? Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ Also note that you should use a try-with-resources statement or a try/finally statement to close your writer at the end - and *not* inside the loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will  be reading up on these now thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your modified code should look like this :

```
  public void save() {

PrintWriter pw=null;
    try{
        pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("directory.txt", true)); 

        for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
            pw.write(x.getName());
            pw.write(x.getNumber());

        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

finally
{
   pw.close();
}

    }
```

as mentioned by Jon Skeet

Comment: yes , it will also run fine, but good is what you told. Thanks, i have modified my answers.

Comment: I would never suggest using `catch (Exception)` like that... we don't know whether the OP should actually declare that their method can throw IOException... and *at least* it should just catch IOException. (I also wouldn't use FileWriter or PrintWriter, but...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, it is generally i used to handle most of the Exception , but really i forgot to mentioned Exception to IOException for PrintWriter class.

Comment: Do you mean you *often* catch `Exception`? Ick!

Comment: @Jon Skeet, yes it is, i dont remember as most of the exception throws by statements, so gets help from IDE(Eclipse) or i use Exception generally.

Comment: That's a *really* bad idea. That means there are all kinds of exceptions you shouldn't be catching (because they indicate bugs). I rarely *catch* exceptions anyway, preferring to let them propagate up...

Comment: Thanks , i will also refer the doc mentioned by you for checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here have some flaws, this is probably what you want if you're using Java 7 or later:

```
public void save() {
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("directory.txt", true))) {         
        for (DirectoryEntry x : theDirectory) {
            pw.write(x.getName());
            pw.write(x.getNumber());                
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // handle the exception
    }   
}
```